# twilio get list of messages for some period smaller then 1 day

Tags: java, twilio

It is possible to get messages from twilio for some period smaller then 1 day.

Currently I founded only this filters:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters

It is possible to get messages for smaller period, f.e. 1 hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I don't believe the API supports filtering messages to intervals smaller than a day.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Devin, it is helpful.